# How to download file with client in ASP.NET Core and react?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a project with ASP.NET Core and react. I want click the button that generate and download a text in docx file.

I use this code in the backend:

```
    // Creates a new instance of WordDocument (Empty Word Document)
    using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument())
    {
        // Adds a section and a paragraph to the document
        document.EnsureMinimal();

        // Appends text to the last paragraph of the document
        document.LastParagraph.AppendText(text);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        // Saves the Word document to  MemoryStream
        document.Save(stream, FormatType.Docx);
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Download Word document in the browser
        return File(stream, "application/msword", name + ".docx");
    }
```

and I get save dialog box for docx file but saved file is corrupted (unreachable content).

I use above code in a ASP.NET MVC (razor) sample and is OK.

I don't know handle in client (react) returned file.

Comment: Did you try to close the document (document.close()) and next return the stream? Even you could try to return the document outside of the using block....

Comment: @Mark no I am not close document. all code in backend is it.
for a note, I use Syncfusion.DocIO.Net.Core nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your data is not in `HTML` format.Try below code to create correct html format that Word can open it.

```
var name="myFile";
var text = `<html><body>${response.data}</body></html>`;
var blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'application/msword' });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var link = document.createElement('A');
link.href = url;
link.download = `${name}.doc`;
link.click();
```